# how to change menu title from login to logout in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

unable to change in menu title nearby home, on successfully login, session created successfully but menu title is not modifiable to Logout from Login.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your code, mate ?

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a menu item created in nav menu via admin, it must be added via the code using function `wp_loginout();`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout